# Set height of all col-sm- equal in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am facing a problem in setting height of all col-sm-3, I tried row-eq-height class but it set all columns into one row

My code is

`

```
<div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="col-sm-3" style="margin-bottom:20px;"><img src="ch4.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block"> <p style="font-size:20px; text-align:center">I am a text I am  a text I am a text</p></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3" style="margin-bottom:20px;"><img src="ch4.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block"> <p style="font-size:20px; text-align:center">I am a text I am  a text I am a text I am a text I am  a text I am a text</p></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3" style="margin-bottom:20px;"><img src="ch4.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block"> <p style="font-size:20px; text-align:center">I am a text I am  a text I am a text</p></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3" style="margin-bottom:20px;"><img src="ch4.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block"> <p style="font-size:20px; text-align:center">I am a text I am  a text I am a text</p></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3" style="margin-bottom:20px;"><img src="ch4.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block"><p style="font-size:20px; text-align:center">I am a text I am  a text I am a text</p></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3" style="margin-bottom:20px;"><img src="ch4.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block"><p style="font-size:20px; text-align:center">I am a text I am  a text I am a text I am a text I am  a text I am a text</p></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3" style="margin-bottom:20px;"><img src="ch4.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block"> <p style="font-size:20px; text-align:center">I am a text I am  a text I am a text I am a text I am  a text I am a text</p></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3" style="margin-bottom:20px;"><img src="ch4.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block"> <p style="font-size:20px; text-align:center">I am a text I am  a text I am a text</p></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3" style="margin-bottom:20px;"><img src="ch4.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block"> <p style="font-size:20px; text-align:center">I am a text I am  a text I am a text</p></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3" style="margin-bottom:20px;"><img src="ch4.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block"> <p style="font-size:20px; text-align:center">I am a text I am  a text I am a text</p></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3" style="margin-bottom:20px;"><img src="ch4.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block"> <p style="font-size:20px; text-align:center">I am a text I am  a text I am a text</p></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3" style="margin-bottom:20px;"><img src="ch4.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block"> <p style="font-size:20px; text-align:center">I am a text I am  a text I am a text</p></div>

        </div>
      </div>
```

Output I am getting is like

[Output screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPZhr.jpg)

I want to remove these blank spaces caused due to longer text in some col-sm-3

Answer (score 0):

Use this css may this help you..

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.row > [class*='col-'] {
  display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-3" style="margin-bottom:20px;"><img src="ch4.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block"> <p style="font-size:20px; text-align:center">I am a text I am  a text I am a text</p></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-3" style="margin-bottom:20px;"><img src="ch4.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block"> <p style="font-size:20px; text-align:center">I am a text I am  a text I am a text I am a text I am  a text I am a text</p></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-3" style="margin-bottom:20px;"><img src="ch4.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block"> <p style="font-size:20px; text-align:center">I am a text I am  a text I am a text</p></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-3" style="margin-bottom:20px;"><img src="ch4.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block"> <p style="font-size:20px; text-align:center">I am a text I am  a text I am a text</p></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-3" style="margin-bottom:20px;"><img src="ch4.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block"><p style="font-size:20px; text-align:center">I am a text I am  a text I am a text</p></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-3" style="margin-bottom:20px;"><img src="ch4.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block"><p style="font-size:20px; text-align:center">I am a text I am  a text I am a text I am a text I am  a text I am a text</p></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-3" style="margin-bottom:20px;"><img src="ch4.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block"> <p style="font-size:20px; text-align:center">I am a text I am  a text I am a text I am a text I am  a text I am a text</p></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-3" style="margin-bottom:20px;"><img src="ch4.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block"> <p style="font-size:20px; text-align:center">I am a text I am  a text I am a text</p></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-3" style="margin-bottom:20px;"><img src="ch4.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block"> <p style="font-size:20px; text-align:center">I am a text I am  a text I am a text</p></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-3" style="margin-bottom:20px;"><img src="ch4.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block"> <p style="font-size:20px; text-align:center">I am a text I am  a text I am a text</p></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-3" style="margin-bottom:20px;"><img src="ch4.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block"> <p style="font-size:20px; text-align:center">I am a text I am  a text I am a text</p></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-3" style="margin-bottom:20px;"><img src="ch4.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block"> <p style="font-size:20px; text-align:center">I am a text I am  a text I am a text</p></div>

        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks. It works for full screen but in mobile view div with longer text is taking full width of screen while div with small text taking 70% width of screen

Comment: updating my answer check.

Comment: Thank you very much